# Is there a way to use Autodesk Tandem API to visualize the 3D visual in a Data Visualization software or shall I go through 3rd party integration?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, autodesk, autodesk-tandem

I want to take the 3D visual and display it on Power BI. Is there a way to do that using the native Autodesk Tandem API?

I interested in visualizing the 3d visual into Power BI or Data Vizualisation Softwares. Is that possible or shall I go through 3rd party integration like Speckle, VIM etc?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an official way, but there is a prototype and sample, you can work off.

1. Start with embedding the viewer, using the new Docs here:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/tandem/v1/code_samples/embedviewer/

2. Then click on the link to 'Power Bi' in 'Other Resources'
3. Adapt the powerBi code for your own reports.

At the moment, this is only a sample, so it will require PowerBi developer knowledge.

If this is something you want to see as 'off the shelf', then you can vote for this feature: 'submit an idea'

https://intandem.autodesk.com/our-product-roadmap/